# Magento: Getting the transaction ID via soap

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, magento-1.7

i recently tried to connect to a magento webshop via magentos SOAPv2 adapter.
Sharpdevelop did generate some c# wrappers getting the WSDL.
I could login and query orders, but when it comes to payment methods I was wondering why there's no way to get the transaction ID.
Here's what I tried:

```
salesOrderEntity ent = ms.salesOrderInfo(mlogin,"<my_order_id>");
```

The `salesOrderEntity` class contains a `salesOrderPaymentEntity` which should contain an attribute `last_trans_id`, but it doesn't.
Does anyone have an idea where to get the transaction ID from payment information? I didn't even find a reference to last_trans_id in the proxy code generated by sharpdevelop.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
-chris-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time i took up this question again and found a solution in my case.
A salesOrderEntity contains a list of salesOrderStatusHistoryEntity objects.
And those contain a field named 'comment' where in my case the Transaction IDs can by found in a textual way like

> Transaction ID:"800736757864..."

This helped me.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the pointer.  Absolutely ridiculous we've got to dig the transaction ID for the order out of the comments in the sales order history.

Answer (score 0):

Chris the OP has answered the question, but just to add some extra value to this Q&A here's the code I've got working.

As some background, the reason I am using Transaction IDs at all is because they are used by Paypal.  I'm writing a cron job that pulls the Paypal orders from the Paypal API for the previous 24 hours, then we pull all orders from Magento via SOAP for the previous 24 hours, get the transaction IDs and match them to the Paypal list. It's to make sure there are no Paypal orders which are not on Magento, occasionally we get an IPN failure which prevents Magento quotes being converted to orders and the customer gets billed by Paypal but no product is shipped to them as the order is never created.  If there's a mismatch an email alert is sent to customer services.

```
$startDate = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', time()));

$complex_params =array(
    array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'from','value' => $startDate)) 
);

$result = $client_v2->salesOrderList($session_id, array('complex_filter' => $complex_params));


// We've got all the orders, now we need to run through them and get the transaction id from the order info

// We create an array just to hold the transaction Ids
$ikoTransactionIds = array();

foreach ($result as $invoice) {

    $invoiceInfo = $client_v2->salesOrderInfo($session_id, $invoice->increment_id);

    $history = $invoiceInfo->status_history;

    $comments = $history[0]->comment;

    // Only the Paypal based records have transaction Ids in the comments, orders placed via credit card do not. In these cases $comments are null
    if ($comments) {

        // Check if the text 'Transaction ID:' exists at all
        if ((strpos($comments, "Transaction ID:")) !== FALSE) { 

            list($before, $transactionId) = explode('Transaction ID: ', $comments);

            // Remove the trailing period
            $transactionId = rtrim($transactionId ,".");

            // Remove the quotes
            $transactionId = str_replace('"', '', $transactionId);

            // We add the id to our array of ids for this Magento install
            $ikoTransactionIds[] = $transactionId;

        }

    } 

}
```